# Android: Assign Drawable Ids to downloaded images

Tags: android, android-drawable

Is there's a way to assign ID to downloaded images? I have a project that all the images are access by IDs, but now the specs has been changed and I need to download images at runtime. I don't want to change how I access the images, because it will cost a fortune for changing it.

If it's not possible to assign IDs during runtime, is there's anyway I can do to minimize the changes for accessing the images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to assign IDs (like in R.drawable.some_image) to downloaded images, because those IDs are generated at compile-time by the Android SDK and hard-coded in your apk. Nothing in the apk can be modified without recompiling it (think layout xml files, drawables, etc...)

Comment: yeah... I kinda figure this out when I post this question. What is your suggestion for this kinda situation?

Comment: well, there's nothing you can do but change your code so that all images are loaded by Bitmap instead...